# Duplicating stderr compilation output into separate file

Tags: windows, batch-file, makefile, cmd

I have a project, which builds by using **make**, and I want to add possibility
to analyze overall state of warning messages.

My idea is change **make** rules in order to duplicate **stderr** compilation output into separate file during full rebuild. Means each time **make all** will be done, all output will be printed in console and in addition **stderr** output will be duplicating into separate file.

This warning report file will be added into repository, so that I will have possibility to compare warnings existing in repository and local warnings.

The question is how to DUPLICATE (not redirect) stderr output into separate file? Means how I should change **all** target in **Makefile**?

I know how to redirect **stderr** output (**make all 2>warning_report.txt**), but it is not
what I need. Warning messages should be both in main console output and in warning file.

I use *Windows 7* as work environment but I had no any deal with *Windows* command line or batch files before.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited:**

In my case final solution looks like below:

`make all 3>&1 1>&2- 2>&3- | tee.bat warning_report.txt`

In this case script **tee.bat**, which is written in *JScript* for *Windows*, I took from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711839/using-a-custom-tee-command-for-bat-file/10719322#10719322) specified by PA (thanks).

What about swapping, I took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507816/with-bash-how-can-i-pipe-standard-error-into-another-process) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/63705/how-to-pipe-stderr-without-piping-stdout).

Comment: see this previous question at SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711839/using-a-custom-tee-command-for-bat-file/10719322#10719322

Comment: Why don't you just redirect it to a file and then display the files contents?

Comment: Because compile time of whole project is approximately 5 minutes.

Comment: Just curious, what does the compile time have to do with my comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about windows but you can do it using `tee` command in Linux. tee is used to redirect STDOUT to file as well as console so you can take its advantage and check if you can solve your problem.

`make all 2>&1 1>stdout.log | tee stderr.log`

redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT`, redirect `STDOUT` to `stdout.log` and all the `STDERR` is copied to `stderr.log` ans echoed on the console as well.

But the solution is not complete yet. The `STDOUT` is not printed on the console but only copied to the `stdout.log`. Try playing around the commands you will get the solution .

Answer (score 0):

I just re-read your question and decided I would try to answer it.

Here's a snippet made to export `stderr` and display it.

```
@echo off
if exist stderr.error del stderr.error
this_is_not_a_command 2>stderr.error
if exist stderr.error type stderr.error & del stderr.error
```

This would export `stderr` to a file and then display the contents of that file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

As now I have no access to my PC, I can't try this now.
I will try in Monday.

Comment: How did it go? Does it help?

Comment: I had tried to use this but eventually I used solution explained above (see section **edited** [above](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15267261/1039412)).